# ng-click does not work properly in left navigation

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a left navigation which has 4 sub-items in it along with a expand/collapse button.When i click on any sub-item it renders the html page properly which is associated with it and the expand/collapse button also works fine.But as soon as i click on sub items many times the expand/collapse button stops functioning.

here is the code extract

```
<div class="sidebar" sidebar-directive="state">
    <a href="" id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">>></a>

    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <span class="img-responsive" id="allocation"></span><input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmyallocation.png" ng-click="" /><br /><b>My Allocation</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <span class="img-responsive" id="matrix"></span><input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmytsmatrix.png" ng-click="" /><br /><b>My TS Status</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <span class="img-responsive" id="utilization"></span><input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmyutilization.png" ng-click="" /><br /><b>My Utilization</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
            <span class="img-responsive" id="contacts"></span><input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbcontacts.png" ng-click ="contactsGrid()" /><br /><b>Contacts</b>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div> 


 $scope.state = false; 
 $scope.toggleState = function () {
    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
    var el = document.getElementById("navigation-toggle"); 
    if (el.innerHTML === "&gt;&gt;") {
       el.innerHTML = "&lt;&lt;"; //document.getElementById('navigation-toggle').style.display = 'none'; 
  } else {
     el.innerHTML = "&gt;&gt;"; 
  }
};
```

Comment: this is the js file -                                                                              $scope.state = false;
        $scope.toggleState = function () {
            $scope.state = !$scope.state;
            var el = document.getElementById("navigation-toggle");
            if (el.innerHTML === "&gt;&gt;") {
                el.innerHTML = "&lt;&lt;";
                //document.getElementById('navigation-toggle').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.innerHTML = "&gt;&gt;";
            }
        };

Comment: Include this in your question. In comments it is very very not good

Comment: Go through this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ZZHFVLC9MsLIy8mhKQ7I?p=preview and explain your problem. I think its working fine

Comment: Hi Charan, Thanks for your quick reply .I have edited the plunker here is the plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/ePscWDIvcyoDYnXihwqF/

Comment: The problem is when i click on contact button(multiple times) which renders an html page the expand/collapse button stops functioning.

Comment: Plunker is not working as `app-name="plunker"` instead of `"myApp"`. I changed that, nothing happens. Its just reloading the plunker when I click on the button

Comment: Because of `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` as you mentioned but not defined anywhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132455/discussion-between-charan-cherry-and-ritesh).

Comment: Please see these plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/NUorNdLaqISeWLnlxh4P?p=preview

Comment: Its working fine right. What is the problem?

Comment: When i click on Contacts image it shows the contact page and the left nav also works fine but when i click contacts image two to three times the navigation button stops working. I have replicated the same issue in the plunker given below. Please have a look at it. Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/NUorNdLaqISeWLnlxh4P?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should do this with interpolation:

```js
$scope.ltgt = ">>";
$scope.state = false;
$scope.toggleState = function() {
  $scope.state = !$scope.state;
  $scope.ltgt = $scope.state ? "<<" : ">>";
};
```

Now in the view:

```
<a href="" id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">{{ltgt}}</a>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('dApp', []);

app.controller('dCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ltgt = ">>";
  $scope.state = false;
  $scope.toggleState = function() {
    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
    $scope.ltgt = $scope.state ? "<<" : ">>";
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='dApp'>
  <div ng-controller='dCtrl'>
    <div class="sidebar" sidebar-directive="state">
      <a href="" id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">{{ltgt}}</a>

      <ul class="navigation" ng-if="state == false">
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <span class="img-responsive" id="allocation"></span>
          <input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmyallocation.png" ng-click="" />
          <br /><b>My Allocation</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <span class="img-responsive" id="matrix"></span>
          <input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmytsmatrix.png" ng-click="" />
          <br /><b>My TS Status</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <span class="img-responsive" id="utilization"></span>
          <input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbmyutilization.png" ng-click="" />
          <br /><b>My Utilization</b>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <span class="img-responsive" id="contacts"></span>
          <input type="image" src="Images/icon_dbcontacts.png" ng-click="contactsGrid()" />
          <br /><b>Contacts</b>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jai.But the issue is related to the navigation button not working on click of contacts icon many times.Here is the plunker:  plnkr.co/edit/NUorNdLaqISeWLnlxh4P?p=preview